# How to style my content within shortcode of azuretoggleshowhide plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am currently using https://wordpress.org/plugins/azurecurve-toggle-showhide/

When I try to style anything within the content, it gets stripped away and there is absolutely no styling of the content.

An Example

```
[toggle title_font_size='20px' title='<strong>About</strong>' border='none' disable_image=1]
<span style='font-style: italic;'>Design is to communicate perception and thought.</span>


<strong>example</strong> is a multi-disciplinary boutique creative agency

[/toggle]
```

Eventually the codes would come out as

```
<p>Design is to communicate perception and thought.</p>
<p>example is a multi-disciplinary boutique creative agency</p>
```

How can I style the content?

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the plugin code.  It looks like it's using `$content = do_shortcode($content);` to return the content you're putting in.  This strips any HTML from the text.  As you can see, it's ignoring the `<span>` you used and converting everything to paragraphs.  You have a few options here.

1. Go to line 146 of azurecurve-toggle-showhide.php in the plugin files and delete `$content = do_shortcode($content);`.  Extremely hacky, but it's easy and will probably do the trick.  You'll also need to avoid updating the plugin to prevent the change from being overwritten.
2. If you can forgo the bolded "example" part, you could wrap the shortcode in a div with a class, and then use CSS selectors to target the first paragraph. Ex:

   ```
   .wrapper p:first-child {
       font-style: italic;
   }
   ```
3. Build your own shortcode or use a different plugin. (Ideal solution)